# setting a property in __init__

Tags: python, class, properties, attributes

I want to create a child class `B` from `A` and use the `__init__` from `A` because it's identical up to one attribute/property.

The following code shows what I would like to do

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 1
        self.c = 1

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # because I want 'a' and 'b', (but not 'c')

    @property
    def c(self):
        return 2

B()
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-95c544214e48> in <module>()
     13         return 2
     14 
---> 15 B()

<ipython-input-9-95c544214e48> in __init__(self)
      7 class B(A):
      8     def __init__(self):
----> 9         super().__init__()  # because I want 'a' and 'b', (but not 'c')
     10 
     11     @property

<ipython-input-9-95c544214e48> in __init__(self)
      3         self.a = 1
      4         self.b = 1
----> 5         self.c = 1
      6 
      7 class B(A):

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I thought that I could solve this issue by doing

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # because I want 'a' and 'b', (but not 'c')
        self.c = property(lambda s: 2)
```

However when then calling:

```
>>> B().c
<property at 0x116f5d7c8>
```

the property is not evaluated.

How can I properly do this without manually copying `__init__` from `A`?

Comment: It sounds to me like `B` shouldn't really inherit from `A` at all. A common superclass might be appropriate.

Comment: It's a little hard to understand your use-case here because you have anonymised it so much. Do you actually need B.c to be a property, or is that an illustration? Is there a reason you can't simply set `self.c = 2` after calling super()?

Comment: The use-case is (still simpler than what I want) that there are many methods of `A` that use `c`, however `B` adds some functionality and makes `c` a `list` instead of a `number`, then the property `c` is taking the average of that `list`.

Comment: For the actual use-case see https://gitlab.kwant-project.org/qt/adaptive/merge_requests/70/diffs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to remedy that is to turn `c` into a property in `A` as well; the property just returns the (private) member `self._c`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 1
        self._c = 1

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self._c

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # because I want 'a' and 'b', (but not 'c')
        self._c = 2

    # is already inherited from A
    # @property
    # def c(self):
    #     return self._c

a = A()
b = B()
print(a.c)  # 1
print(b.c)  # 2
```

---

if you can't change `A` (and assuming that the purpose of your property is to make `c` read-only), this is a variant: the `c.setter` will raise an error, if `self._c` is not `None`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 1
        self.c = 1

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self._c = None
        super().__init__()  # the setter for c will work as self._c = None
        self._c = 2         # now we set c to the new value 
                            # (bypassing the setter)

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self._c

    @c.setter
    def c(self, value):
        if self._c is not None:
            raise AttributeError
        self._c = value
```

Comment: Let's assume that I can't change the `__init__` of `A`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The complexity of your second answer made me realize that it's easier to go with your first suggestion. I've implemented this in https://gitlab.kwant-project.org/qt/adaptive/merge_requests/70/diffs :)